# count elements with same attribute value

Tags: xslt

I bet this is an easy one but I cant solve it.

Im trying to cound the nods that have the same value in an XML file

I want the output be 7 type 2.

When Im using the count function It count all the type nods and not the type = 2 nods.

```
<autoads>
<ad>
<type>1</type>
</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>
</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>1</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>1</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>

</ad>
<ad>
<type>2</type>
</ad><br />
</autoads>
```

Comment: it's not attribute, it's value; attribute would be `<type someAttribute="someValue">1</type>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
count(/*/*/type[. = 2])
```

this produces the number of elements named `type`, whose string value converted to number is `2` and that are grand-children of the top element of the XML document.

Comment: It amazing how easy Its looks. Thank you alot friend.

Comment: @FelipeOtarola: You are welcome. Yes, XPath is a powerful and elegant language.